Power Query & Data Refresh
I apologize if my question seems basic, but I’m new to this. If I publish my report to Power BI Service, will the changes I made in Power Query be applied to new data during the next refresh? What potential issues might arise, and what should I watch out for?
Here's the suggested answer by Chatgpt, do you agree ?
Data Consistency: Ensure that the new data follows the same structure as the data used when you created the queries. Any changes in column names, data types, or data formats in the new dataset could cause errors or unexpected results during the refresh.
Data Source Permissions: Verify that the credentials and permissions for the data source in Power BI Service are properly configured. If there are any issues with accessing the data source, the refresh might fail.
Query Performance: Be aware of the performance of your queries. Large or complex transformations can slow down the refresh process. Optimize your queries where possible to improve performance.
Error Handling: Implement error handling in your Power Query steps to manage any issues that might arise during data refresh. This can include adding checks or handling null values.
Scheduled Refresh: If you rely on scheduled refreshes, ensure they are properly configured and monitored. Check the refresh history regularly to identify any issues that might need addressing.
Data Model Changes: If you make changes to the data model or relationships, verify that these changes are reflected correctly in your report and do not break existing visualizations or calculations.

Presuming you are using powerbi applications and publishing those  applications... If you publish the changes, then yes.  The next refresh will use the most recent version of the published application which will include your changes.
